# Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Does the keras functional API impose that the number of batch elements in models output equals to the number of elements in their input? For instance, the code bellow raises an exception: `ValueError: Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size. Output shape = (1, 1), expected output shape = shape (2, 1)`:

```
d = 2
input_ = Input(shape=(d, ))
output_ = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_sum(x, keepdims=True))(input_)
model = keras.Model(name='model', inputs=input_, outputs=output_)
```

If I set `keepdims` to false, another exception is raised:  `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`, which makes sense as the model expects a batch of elements, each of which being a 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tensorflow Keras functional API** doesn't necessarily impose that the number of batch elements in model output equals to the number of elements in their input.
Tensorflow handles this by leaving the **index 0** of the Output shape to **None**, for it to be **batch_size agnostic**.

But in this case, when `model.summary()` is printed, you can observe that the last layer output shape is fixed to `(1,1)` rather than `(None,1)`.
Which will work normally if you will **only** feed it data with `batch_size = 1`, but will **raise an error** when the data fed have `batch_size != 1`.

More specifically: `Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size. Output shape = (1, 1), expected output shape = shape (BATCH_SIZE, 1)`.

Expected output shape `(BATCH_SIZE,1)` is the output shape of your **data**.

Output shape `(1, 1)` is the output shape of the **model**.